# using custom meta user data to run queries in WordPress

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, user-meta

I have added custom  user meta data to the WordPress user profile below is the code I used to add this data.  This part of the code seems to be working fine and I do not have a problem with it.

```
<?php

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//   Adding a Field to Wordpress User Profile
//   http://scriptbaker.com/adding-custom-fields-to-wordpress-user-profile-                    
and-add-new-user-page/
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function custom_user_profile_fields($user){
    if(is_object($user))
{
    $company = esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'company', $user->ID ) );
    $mf_group = esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'mf_group', $user->ID ) );
}
else
{
    $company = null;
    $phone =  null;
    $insurens =  null;
}
?>
<h3>Extra profile information</h3>
<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="company">Company Name</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="regular-text" name="company" value="<?php echo $company; ?>" id="company" /><br />
        </td>

        <th>
            <label for="phone">MF Group</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="regular-text" name="mf_group" value="<?php echo $mf_group; ?>" id="mf_group" /><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( "user_new_form", "custom_user_profile_fields" );

function save_custom_user_profile_fields($user_id){
# again do this only if you can
if(!current_user_can('manage_options'))
    return false;

# save my custom field
update_user_meta($user_id, 'company', $_POST['company']);
update_user_meta($user_id, 'mf_group', $_POST['mf_group']);
}
add_action('user_register', 'save_custom_user_profile_fields');
add_action('profile_update', 'save_custom_user_profile_fields');


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// add columns to User panel list page
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function add_user_columns($column) {
$column['company'] = 'Company';
$column['mf_group'] = 'MF Group';

    return $column;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'add_user_columns' );

//add the data
function add_user_column_data( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    $user = get_userdata($user_id);

    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'company' :
            return $user->company;
            break;
        default:
    }
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'mf_group' :
            return $user->mf_group;
                break;
        default:
    }
   return;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'add_user_column_data', 10, 3 );

?>
```

The problem comes when I want to use this metadata to run queries.  Below is a example of where I would like to use this  meta data.

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
?>
<div class="row">
         <div class="col-md text-center">
          <h2>
              Welcome To your Dashboard 
              </h2>
         </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md text-center  bg-success">
                        All
                        <?php
                                        $args = array(
                                    'post_type'     => 'maintenances',
                                    'post_status'   => 'published',
                                        'taxonomy'      => 'maintenance-type',
                                    'term'          => 'All',
                                    'numberposts'   => -1,
                                    'author'        => $current_user->ID,
                                    'company'       => $current_user->company,
                                    'mf_group'      => $current_user->mf_group,
                                    );
                                    $num_1 = count( get_posts( $args ) );
                                    $sum_total = $num_1 / $num_1 * 100;
                        ?>
                        <h2 class="align-middle">
                                    <?php echo $num_1 ;?><br />
                                    100 %<br />
                        </h2>
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

'company'       => $current_user->company,

'mf_group'      => $current_user->mf_group,

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

this line of code does not seem to be working

if I would Echo the two lines like this

```
$client             =   $current_user->company;

$mfgroup            =   $current_user->mf_group;
 //////////////////////////////////////<br/>

             Cleint <strong><?php echo $client ?></strong><br/>

             Mf Group <strong><?php echo $mfgroup ?></strong><br/>



             ///////////////////////////////////////<br/>
```

it does return the correct values from the database

Could Somebody please advise me on the way forward into using this Mega data to run queries thank you

Comment: User meta belongs to users, not posts. I’m not sure what results you expect querying posts with user meta.

Comment: The ides it the use the querying posts with user meta to get different  results base on the current user role.


query one

User Role = store
querying only the user post 
..
    'author'     => $current_user->ID,
    

query two  
User Role = area manager
querying post made by mf_group.  The mf_group has get more than oneuser link to it.
..
    'mf_group'  => $current_user->mf_group,

query three
User Role = site manager
querying post made by company.
'company'  => $current_user->company,

Comment: Sorry, still don’t understand. So you’re also storing these values as post meta? `company` is not a valid argument for `get_posts`.

Answer (score 0):

**wp_get_current_user()** does not return all the data for the user, you should try using **get_user_meta()**. Try as below

```
$company = get_user_meta($current_user->ID,'company');
$mf_group = get_user_meta($current_user->ID,'mf_group');
```

and in your post loop changes this two lines as below

```
'company'       => $company[0],
'mf_group'      => $mf_group[0],
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you by not working

The ides it the use the querying posts with user meta to get different results base on the current user role.

query one
User Role = store querying only the user post
    `.. 'author' => $current_user->ID,`

query two
User Role = area manager querying post made by mf_group.
The mf_group has get more than oneuser link to it.
    `.. 'mf_group' => $current_user->mf_group,`

query three
User Role = site manager querying post made by company.
    `..company' => $current_user->company,`

Comment: @MFWebMaster , still not getting what you wan't to do.